# How filter features by status

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to show in my map in a cluster layer filtering by if is opened or not. How can do it? Should I create two layers?

One with filter: `filter["has", "opened"]` and other with filter: `filter["!", ["has", "opened"]]`?

```
export const clusterLayerOpened = {
    id: "clusters",
    type: "circle",
    source: "earthquakes",
    filter: ["has", "opened"],
    paint: {
        "circle-color": [ "step", ["get", "opened"], "#51bbd6",100,"#f1f075",750,"#f28cb1", ],
        "circle-radius": ["step", ["get", "opened"], 20, 100, 30, 750, 40],
    },
};

export const clusterLayerNoOpened = {
    id: "clusters",
    type: "circle",
    source: "earthquakes",
    filter: ["!", ["has", "opened"]],
    paint: {
        "circle-color": [ "step", ["get", "opened"], "#51bbd6",100,"#f1f075",750,"#f28cb1", ],
        "circle-radius": ["step", ["get", "opened"], 20, 100, 30, 750, 40],
    },
};
```

This is my geojson:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "ak16994521",
                "mag": 2.3,
                "time": 1507425650893,
                "felt": null,
                "tsunami": 0,
                "opened": true
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-151.5129, 63.1016, 0.0]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "ak16994519",
                "mag": 1.7,
                "time": 1507425289659,
                "felt": null,
                "tsunami": 0,
                "opened": false
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-150.4048, 63.1224, 105.5]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to create two separate layers to filter by whether the a point has been opened or not. Here is some code showing how to add a layer which displays all points with the property `"opened": true`, and hides all points with `"opened": false`:

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'opened',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'points',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 10,
    'circle-opacity': ["match", ["to-string", ["get", "opened"]], 'true', 1 , 'false', 0, 0]
  }
});
```

To instead show all points with the property `"opened": false`, you can switch the `'circle-opacity'` expression to read:

```
["match", ["to-string", ["get", "opened"]], 'true', 0 , 'false', 1, 0]
```

This code makes use of a few Mapbox [expressions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/). I've linked the documentation to each relevant expression here: [`match`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#match), [`to-string`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#types-to-string), and [`get`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get).

Here is a JSFiddle where two layers are added to the map: https://jsfiddle.net/hpkzrm4n/. The points with `"opened": true` are shown in red and the points with `"opened": false` are shown in blue. Note that you will need to add your own Mapbox access token where indicated in order to view the results. Here is a screenshot, as a preview:

[image: Preview of code in JSFiddle]

Comment: Ok, but the idea it is to show in cluster layer, layers that are opened or not.
Whit two layers as you are doing works but when I do zoom in doesnt split/divide.
How can do that when I zoom in divide in point that are opened and not opened???

Comment: By "opened" or "not opened," are you referring to a property in your GeoJSON (i.e. "opened": true or "opened": false, as provided in your example GeoJSON), or a property determined by some sort of user interaction? It almost sounds like you're using the term "opened" to mean that a user has clicked on a cluster or something. It would be really helpful if you could clarify this :)

Comment: In the meantime, you might find the documentation for the GeoJSON source's cluster property: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-cluster, as well as these three GL JS methods related to expanding clusters: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#getclusterexpansionzoom, https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#getclusterchildren, https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#getclusterleaves.